# How to do multiple filtering on a queryset

Tags: python, django

I Need to make a rest api endpoint where the user can filter with multiple get parameters which are fields of the corresponding model.

I got the list of model fields and obtained the get parameter values, i need to filter the all results by the given get parameters

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    query_set = models.Resident.objects.all()
    fields = models.Resident._meta.get_fields()
    for x in fields:
        fieldValue = self.request.GET.get(x.name)
        fieldName = x.name
        if fieldValue is not None:
            query_set.filter(**{fieldName: fieldValue})          
    return query_set
```

suppose if the user wanted to filter by username=foo & email=email@meail.com the queryset should return the value which matches the both conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out, i have been iterating over the queryset without saving the previous filter,finally changed the code like this below, works like charm

```
def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    query_set = models.Resident.objects
    fields = models.Resident._meta.get_fields()
    for x in fields:
        fieldValue = self.request.GET.get(x.name)
        fieldName = x.name
        if fieldValue is not None:
            query_set = query_set.filter(**{fieldName: fieldValue})          
    return query_set
```